# Run Automated Tests After Team Build On Physical Environment

Tags: automated-tests, testcase, coded-ui-tests

We are trying to automate our tests but we have some problems.

Our solution has 7 projects, one of them is WCF server and one of them is Windows Forms project. Others are helper projects.

We created a test plan and test cases. We runned our test cases with action recording and converted manual tests to Coded UI test. After that, we assoiciate our coded ui test with test case.

We defined a new build. This new build deploys WCF server to IIS and transform app.config and copy client application files to a folder.

We setted up test controller and test agent at same build machine.

I wonder what need we to do to automate our build and test?
How our build trig automated test?

Because of VMWare infrastructure we can't use Lab Management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

1. I used msdeploy to deploy WCF service
2. I created a database project and used VSDBCMD tool
3. I installed test controller and test agent my build server
4. I created test settings for automated tests and configured to use this agent
5. I attached my coded ui test with test case

Then it is ok :)